# How do I export only additions when running export-diff to a shapefile in geogit (geogig)?

Tags: shapefile, boundless-suite

I currently have two commits in my GeoGit (GeoGig) repository.  I'm running the following command on the two commits to get the differences exported to a shapefile.

`geogit shp export-diff [commit1] [commit2] [path] differences.shp`

I know doing the `diff` command that there are X number of Additions, X modifications, and X removals.

The shapefile creating is providing me both additions, removals, and modifications, but what I would like is a shapefile showing only the additions, a shapefile showing only the removals, and a shapefile showing the modifications, or possibly add a column to the shapefile showing what the status of the feature is (A, R, M).  Is this even possible with GeoGit (GeoGig) currently, and if so what arguments should I add to this statement?